# Are logarithms and nth root of numbers same?

Tags: logarithms

We write $2^3 = 8$ and express the same as $\log (8)$ to the base $2$ is $3$. Isn't this the same as finding nth root of a number? What is the significance of logarithms actually and what if we don't have the concept of Logarithms?

Comment: Its slightly different - if you start with the number 8, you can either take the logarithm base 2 to get 3, which tells you that $2^3=8$, or you take the nth root where $n=3$ to get 2, which tells you the same thing. So the first way, you start with the numbers 8 and 2 and arrive at 3, while the second way, you start with the numbers 8 and 3 and arrive at 2. They both ultimately give you the same relationship, but you started off with different information to get there.

Comment: No.  The $n$th is knowing the final amount and the power and finding the base. The logartihm is knowing the final amount and the base and finding the power.  If you example $\log_2 8 = ??????$ means figuring out $2^{???????} = 8$.  But $\sqrt[3]8 = !!!!!!!!$ means figuring out $!!!!!!!^3 = 8$.

Comment: " Isn't this the same as finding nth root of a number?"  well, if you don't know *what* $n$ is that won't help you.   $\log_2 8 = 3$ and $\sqrt[3] 8 =2$ and $2^3 =8$ are indeed equivalent statements and mean the same thing but they answer three *different* question.  $\log_2 8 = 3$ answers "$2$ to what power equals $8$" and $\sqrt[3] 8= 2$ answers "what to the $3$rd power equals $8$".  And $2^3 = 8$ answers "what is $2$ to the $3$rd power".  Three different questions with three different answers all about the same relation.

Answer (score 5):

The b-th root is the answer to *Which number should we raise to the power $b$ to get $c$* ? ($a = \sqrt[b]{c}$), while the logarithm is the answer to *To which power should we raise the number $a$ to get $c$ ?* ($b=\log_a c$).

Answer (score 3):

$2^3 = 8$ and $\sqrt[3] 8 = 2$ and $\log_2 8 = 3$ all express the same relationship between $2,3$ and $8$.  But the each refer to different aspect of the relation ship.

$\sqrt[3] 8 = \color{red} x$ means to solve $\color{red}x^3 = 8$.  We know what the final result is, and we know the power, but we don't know the base.  That is what $\sqrt[3] 8$ is supposed to express; the base.

$\log_2 8 = \color{green} y$ means to solve $2^{\color{green} y} = 8$.  We know what the final result is and we know the base, but we don't know the power.  That is what $\log_2 8$ is supposed to express; the power.

And $2^3 = \color{blue} z$ means to solve $2^3 = \color{blue}z$.  We know the base and we know the power, but we don't know what the final result.  That is what $2^3$ is supposed to express; the final result.

So $2^3 = 8, \sqrt[3]8 = 2; \log_2 8 = 3$.  One relationship with three different components, and an expression to describe *each* possible component.

Answer (score 1):

One historical significance of logarithms is that they change multiplication into addition, and that was used in practical computation (and inherent in the slide rule as a calculating device) before electronic calculators.

Here are some more mathematically advanced aspects of the logarithm, which give a clue as to why the function emerges so often and across a range of mathematical applications:

Logarithms solve the problem of integrating $\frac 1x=x^{-1}$. Other integer powers of $x$ can be integrated by taking the inverse of obvious derivatives.

The natural logarithm is the inverse function of the exponential function ($e^x$), which is a fixed point of the operation of differentiation.

The discrete logarithm (and associated primitive root of a finite field) are significant in coding theory. This replicates the multiplication to addition aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one answered the question in the manner I would've liked to see myself, here's my answer:

```
base ^ exponent = result/number
```

where, the expression (base ^ exponent) is called '**power**', not the result/number. If you are wondering why the result is not called 'power', check [this link](https://www.quora.com/Does-the-power-of-a-number-refer-only-to-the-exponent-or-is-it-the-base-raised-to-the-exponent/answer/Howard-Ludwig).

For example:

```
2 ^ 3 = 8
```

where, 2 is the 'base', 3 is the 'exponent', the expression (2^3) is the 'power' and 8 is the result/number.

With these terminologies in mind -

Finding ***log*** of a number, given a *base*, is to find the ***exponent*** => log base 2 of 8 = 3.

Finding nth ***root*** or bth root or < whatever >th root of a number, given an *exponent*, is to find the ***base*** => 3rd root of 8 = cube root of 8 = 2.

Hope this helps.